# Adding dynamic controls to a Windows Form not all controls showing up

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a form with multiple DataGridViews. I pass the number of DataGridViews and names of the data tables associated with the DataGridView. But it is only showing one DataGridView when I run the code. I checked the visibility is True, the Locations are different, I even checked if all the DataGridView's are added to the control, they all are fine.

Here's my Code

```
public partial class Tables : Form
{
    private String[] doc_names;
    public Tables(int doctors, String[] names)
    {
        this.Size = new Size(800, 600);
        this.doc_names = names;

        this.Load += new EventHandler(Tables_Load);
    }

    void Tables_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        for (int i = 0; i < doc_names.Length; ++i)
        {

            Label label = new Label();
            label.Location = new Point(10, 10 + 150 * i);
            label.Text = doc_names[i];
            this.Controls.Add(label);

            DataGridView view = new DataGridView();
            view.Name = doc_names[i];
            view.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            view.Size = new Size(150, 150);
            view.Location = new Point(0, 200 * i);


            this.Controls.Add(view);

            populateTable(doc_names[i], view);

        }

        /*Check if the control was added*/
        foreach (Control control in Controls) {
            Console.WriteLine(control.Name);
        }
    }

    /*Binds data to the DataGridView*/
    void populateTable(String doctor, DataGridView dataTable) {
        AppointmentTable table = new AppointmentTable();

        Appointment[] apps = table.getbyDoctor(doctor);
        //Console.WriteLine(doctor);
        dataTable.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        dataTable.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataTable.DataSource = apps;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could it be because you are using `DockStyle.Fill`? Since you control positioning manually via code by setting `view.Location`, could you try to set `view.Dock = DockStyle.None`

Comment: Yes! I try but it not work.

Comment: Have you tried placing controls into a layout panel rather then onto the form itself? Perhaps it's worth to give this approach a try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9w7ek2f(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: There are many issues in the form. For example you added grid with dock style = fill, so the grid fills the form and you can't see anything else. Also if you change the dock style, your label locations are under your grids after 2-3 grids. Also you set the size of form to be 800x600 while count of controls may cause they go beyond your forms height. You should stop adding controls this way. Learn to use [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4yc3e8c(v=vs.100).aspx) and [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9w7ek2f(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: After removing the Dock=Fill and adapting the step of the Labels to the same as the DGVs everything else should be ok. You probalby want to add anchors, though for the DGVs to ake them grow to the right.. And also set the Form to AutoScroll=True;

Comment: thank you.... solve my problem.